# How to open a div selecting a value from dropdown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I  need an application where i have a drop down where i have some values and and my requirement is that when i click any value on that drop down a div will open.I have  implemented that but my code is not properly working.Here  what i have done so far.

```
<div class="form-control">
        <label class="lebelMergin" for="branch_branchTypeId">
            <span class="spanMergin">Office Type<span class="required">*</span></span>
            <s:select name="branch.branchTypeId"  id="branch_branchTypeId" requiredLabel="true" list="%{dataArr['branchTypeList']}" listValue="name"
            listKey="id" headerKey="" headerValue="Select Type" >           
            </s:select>
        </label>                
    </div>

  <div style='display:none;' id='business'>Business Name
    <br/>&nbsp;
    <br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <br/>
    </div> 

<style>
#business {
 display:none;
  }

  </style>


<script>
(function() {

$('#branch_branchTypeId').on('change', function () {
$("#business").css('display', (this.value == '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

But when i clicking on that values  in the drop down  only for one value the input box is coming but i want the functionality for all the  value.Here i am attaching the screen ...For HO the input box is coming but for others it is not. [image]

Comment: you can use toggleClass, to separate logic and css, this will make your life much easier in bigger projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which "option" tags do yo have in your select (dropdown)?
May be this would be help:

```
$('#branch_branchTypeId').on('change', function (event) {
    var vl = $(this).val();
    var target = $("#business");
    if (vl) {
        target.show();
    } else {
        target.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much can i also get the name corresponding to the id ??

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand what did you mean.
If you need to get some extra data from selected option, you can find that option like this:
    `var selectedOption = $('select option:selected');`
In your case it fill be like:
    `var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var someData = selectedOption.attr('value');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your test `this.value == 1`. You can use `this.selectedIndex` instead.

```
$('#branch_branchTypeId').on('change', function () {
    $("#business").css('display', (this.selectedIndex >= 1) ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Following your comment, I assumed that `selectIndex == 0` corresponds to the default option, with `business` div not displayed.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nvdeoab/

Comment: it working bu i want when the default select type will come then the input box will disappear..please help